# Electrical Contact to Digital Signal

Tags: switches, bluetooth

I am not normally into electrical projects or engineering so forgive my ignorance...

I am working on a project that would involve a couple dozen electrical contact switches.  I want all these contacts to be wired together in a central circuit board.  When any of the electrical switches are closed...make contact...the circuit board will detect this and send a signal via Bluetooth to my Macintosh.  The signal would differentiate which of the switches made contact.  My Mac would process this incoming data with custom software that I write (the custom software part I know how to do).

Are there any devices or components out there that will do this without a lot of work?

Thanks...MDCragg

Comment: The simplest method would be Bluetooth serial and a microcontroller. If you're only building one, perhaps a device as follows interfaced to a microcontroller PIC/Atmel/etc.. http://www.iogear.com/product/GBS301/

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Since posting this I started reading about the Arduino and feel I may be able to piece something together using one of those. It seems like use of the Arduino has been dumbed down enough where a dabbler (like I am in this case) can learn their way into it. Again...thanks for the responses. Matt

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is with a Bluetooth IO module.  You buy a working Bluetooth device (the toughest part of the design).  IO is what translates the switch data into Bluetooth packets.

It is not an out of the box solution though.  You will have to hook up your switches to provide the right voltage to the IO pins.  You will also have to write some code to transfer the data, although there are usually examples that will get you close.

This is not really a beginner's project.

An example of a Bluetooth IO module is below but may or may not work depending on the specifics of your design.

http://www.connectblue.com/products/bluetooth-products/bluetooth-modules/bluetooth-io-module-obi411/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any experience building circuits? There are off the shelf solutions for a small number of inputs to a Bluetooth connection (I even have some I've built), but they tend to be 1-8 inputs. If you are looking for a few dozen, then I have to believe you'll be doing some design yourself.

Have you ever used an Arduino? That would be a good DIY introduction.

If you can handle connecting a few switches to an Arduino and writing code to send that data through a Bluetooth shield, then it's not a big jump to making it work for "n-dozen" inputs, but first you have to get started.

So I guess the first question is "what's your level of expertise?"